# echo each date between a given value in PHP

Tags: php

I have a form that allows users to enter a date when they are available in the format dd/mm/yyyy.

What I want to be able to do is `echo` out each date between now (including today) and the date entered.

Could someone help me out? I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

For example, if someone was to enter 12/12/2011 and the date today was 10/12/2011 it would echo the following:

```
10/12/2011  
11/12/2011  
12/12/2011
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are using a DD-MM-YYYY, make sure your separators are - so that you don't have converting them to timestamps. Here is an example with the current format etc.

You should have more checks to make sure you do not get an infinite loop :).

```
$start_date = "10/12/2011";
$end_date = "12/12/2011";
print_r(dates_between($start_date, $end_date));

function dates_between($start_date, $end_date)
{
    $date = array($start_date);
    $start_date = str_replace('/', '-', $start_date);
    $end_date = str_replace('/', '-', $end_date);

    $current_date = $start_date;
    while($current_date != $end_date)
    {
        $current_date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($current_date)));
        $date[] = str_replace('-', '/', $current_date);
    }
    return $date;
}
```

Comment: Im in Australia, so the date format is in dd/mm/yyyy .... How would i go about changing it to mm-dd-yyyy ?

Comment: I'm in Australia too. I have edited the code above to return / instead of -.

Comment: Threw in more changes to make life easier ;)

Comment: Hey, thanks heaps for this ... its helped alot, im having trouble trying to replicate it without using a function though.

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Using != in WHILE is a VERY BAD PRACTICE specially if you do NOT check that start_date is not older than end_date

Comment: @bensiu that is why I had mentioned in my post - **You should have more checks to make sure you do not get an infinite loop :).** Did not want to do all the work for the asker. I think the -ve vote was uncalled for when I had mentioned it in the original post.

Answer (score 4):

```
$start_date = time ();  // today
$end_date = strtotime ( .. your input date as string ... );
while ( $start_date + 86400 < $end_date ) {
  echo date ('m/d/Y', $start_date );
  $start_date += 86400; // full day
}
```

Comment: Nice~ just watch out for DaylightSavings~ It threw a wrench into one of my versions of this. `$end_date=strtotime($_REQUEST['begin'].' noon');` is a little more insulated

Comment: Does the input date thats put into the strtotime have to be formatted a certain way? .... when i put in the date 29/04/2011 into the strtotime, it doesnt echo anything out

Comment: Using epochs is a good trap to fall into. Best to use strtotime, do not ever use +86400.. will land into big troubles. I have dealth with it :).. lesson learnt!

Answer (score 0):

picked from [here](http://prajapatinilesh.wordpress.com/2009/05/07/get-all-dates-between-two-dates-using-php-code/)

```
<?php
$fromDate = ’01/01/2009′;
$toDate = ’01/10/2009′;

$dateMonthYearArr = array();
$fromDateTS = strtotime($fromDate);
$toDateTS = strtotime($toDate);

for ($currentDateTS = $fromDateTS; $currentDateTS <= $toDateTS; $currentDateTS += (60 * 60 * 24)) {
// use date() and $currentDateTS to format the dates in between
$currentDateStr = date(“Y-m-d”,$currentDateTS);
$dateMonthYearArr[] = $currentDateStr;
//print $currentDateStr.”<br />”;
}

echo  “<pre>”;
print_r($dateMonthYearArr);
echo “</pre>”;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Assume dates are properly formatted.
$startDate;
$endDate;

while($startDate < $endDate){  
     $startDate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($startDate))); 
     echo $startDate;

}
```

Comment: I got impresion that it will be never ending while